# Laravel vuejs from sub directory image not showing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

Recently I'm working with `vuejs` my project on subdirectory where my images are not showing which are from `public/images/` directory I searched a lot find many solutions but nothing works for me. but locally it's working fine.

code sample

#### Home.vue

```html
<div class="widget-bg-image absolute">
  <div class="widget-container">
    <div class="image">
      <img width="629" height="424" src="/images/big-banner/3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set root path in `webpack.mix.js` like `mix.setResourceRoot('/subdirectory/')` but nothing happened I also set public path like `mix.setPublicPath('/subdirectory/')`

I tried in:

#### webpack.mix.js

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'))

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
    mix.setResourceRoot(`/${process.env.BASE_URL}/`)
}
```

I want my image path like

```html
  <img width="629" height="424" src="my-host/subdirectory/images/big-banner/3.png">
```

is there any other way to do it.? please help me

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this is adding global view-model configuration-object (VM) within blade-template:

```
@section('footer')
<script>
    var vm = {
        root: '{{ url('/') }}' + "/",    // could include other variables as well, such as translations and/or session-objects from PHP
    } 
</script>
@endsection
```

I'm using Vue 3, so I'm adding this variable to Vue-application with:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$vm = window.vm;

// or in Vue 2

Vue.prototype.$vm = window.vm;
```

This way you can add root-path for your images to template:

```
<img :src="$vm.root + 'images/file.jpg'" />
```

As long as you can access file with your browser at that url you should be fine. Otherwise the problem could be that the file doesn't really exist at given url, so check path if you have any issues.

Comment: this way, components problems will solve but how can I do that in the CSS  file `background-image`

Comment: I wouldn't mix vue, css(scss) and webkit this way when thinking of th answer, even though it's possible with other solutions. Instead I would simply think a solution for question "how can I pass PHP configuration variable to CSS/SCSS?". Maybe https://joelennon.com/generating-custom-branded-stylesheets-in-laravel-with-scssphp could be an answer? Other solution could be having an inline css-style within blade-template that sets url just as I do for VM. To my knowledge there is no native PHP/Laravel for SCSS -parser included within base Laravel installation. This isn't Laravel specific problem.

Comment: Additionally I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly. If the problem is that you are running Laravel project in www.somehost.com/subdirectory/ and your css is pointing to www.somehost.com/images/file.jpg , then the problem might be that you have absolute path in background-image url instead of relative to your public directory. Have you tried removing the first slash character from your image-url? Because that first slash is telling to search images-folder from the root of your domain.

Comment: Solution might be simple: It seems that Laravel Mix should be able to rewrite urls just as Sharma answered. Still, please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#url-processing (or similar for older version). There is a red exclamation note that absolute urls (which start with slash) are not rewritten. This could be the source of problem if you have something like url('/images/file.jpg') . You most likely won't need env variables for SCSS neither, as webpack should handle url generation out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Set you `BASE_URL` to your project. In `.env` file set

```
BASE_URL=my-host/subdirectory/
```

And set

```
<img width="629" height="424" src={process.env.BASE_URL + "images/big-banner/3.png"}>
```

Comment: where I set `BASE_URL` then..? can you explain with details, please

Comment: Set `BASE_URL` in .env file.

Comment: No error, but url get from host not from subdir